# How to set a value got from one server to another server with ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Follow this guide install Kubernetes cluster:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

## Master Server

```
$ kubeadm init
(got token value here)
```

### Check token

```
# kubeadm token list
TOKEN                     TTL         EXPIRES   USAGES                   DESCRIPTION
abd323.0213903ur10u01r0n   <forever>   <never>   authentication,signing   The default bootstrap token generated by 'kubeadm init'.
```

## Node Server

```
$ kubeadm join --token <token> <master-ip>:<master-port>
```

Here need the token got from master server.

---

If use Ansible to make playbook for this install flow, how to get token value and set to another host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) for that:

```
- debug: msg="{{ hostvars['master'].my_token }}"
```

Comment: Thank you. I had edited the question and added `Check token` part. That way can get the value from output, but how to catch it? Here `my_token` is where to set?

Comment: Please, take some time to read docs page I linked: [registered variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables).